# Is there an extension point in the Intershop back office for payment methods?

Tags: intershop

I'm looking to add a new tab to specific payment methods, after the "Preferences" tab for example, to provide additional functionality to interact with the payment method. The methods are implemented using the Payment services framework.

Unfortunately the Payment cookbook in the Knowledge Base doesn't go into detail about the possible templates here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `payment/PaymentMethodTabs_52.isml`.

There seems to be no extension point. You would have to override this template and add the new tab yourself. Preferably you should override this template, add an extension point and then write some extension that adds new tabs to the screen. This way your code can easily be migrated to the next version of intershop if they added an extension point later.